# Getting undefined method error in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, model, automated-tests, factory-bot

I'm using RSpec and FactoryGirl for testing my models and I'm stuck at "highest_priority" method which can't be seen by RSpec for some reason.

Here's the method itself:

**models/task.rb**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

#some stuff

 def self.highest_priority
    p = Task.order(:priority).last.try(:priority)
    p ? p + 1 : 1
  end
end
```

And when I run **task_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Task do

it "returns highest priority" do
  last_task = FactoryGirl.build(:task, priority: "5")
  last_task.highest_priority
  expect(last_task(:priority)).to eq("6")
 end
end
```

I get the following error:
[image]

When I'm calling this method in my controller like this

```
 def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)
    @task.highest_priority
    @task.complete = false


    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.js
      else
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

And the method looks like

```
  def highest_priority
    self.maximum(:priority).to_i + 1
  end
```

I'm getting

[image]

Comment: let me make sure i get the method correctly, you call it on an instance to set it's priority to the maximum + 1 ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady you described this correctly.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I'm extremely sorry. I reverted to my old method and it's setting "20". That's my fault. I'll be digging through. thanks

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Your method is working.

Comment: I kinda don't understand how it's working, it shouldn't modify the instance's state ( but you want to ? ), if you need to edit the state then you need an instance method

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: `maximum` is a class method, it needs to be `self.class.maximum`

Comment: I've rewrote my answer, please check the updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you better use ActiveRecord's `maximum` instead of ordering and then picking one, you'll avoid the instance initialization and get a number directly from the query

```
Task.maximum(:priority)
```

this could be put in a class method like this

```
def self.maximum_priority
  Task.maximum(:priority) || 0 # fall back to zero if no maximum exists
end
```

Then for the second half which is updating the method, i would create an instance method for that, and using the class method

```
def set_maximum_priority
  self.priority = self.class.maximum_priority + 1

  self
end
```

Note that I returned self at the end for chainability

Then your action would become something like this

```
def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params).set_maximum_priority
    @task.complete = false
    ...
end
```

Comment: You didn't get the point of the Rspec error.. :) Your code is broken still.

Comment: However it's not incrementing the value.

Comment: @BillyLogan ok i didn't notice you wanted that, simply add a +1 to the maximum

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady when priority attribute is zero It's setting "20" value instead of "1" for some reason.

Comment: @BillyLogan maybe cause you have a task with the priority 19 in your db, please reply on my comment on your question and explain what you want the method to do exactly.

Comment: I deleted all the tasks in my app and it's supposed to set "1" priority when adding. However I'm getting "20". In other cases It does increment good.

Answer (score 1):

You  need to create the method as an instance method of `Task` model. Like below :

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  #some stuff

  def highest_priority
    p = Task.order(:priority).last.try(:priority)
    p ? p + 1 : 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. Thank you a lot. but now I'm getting `undefined method last_task`. Do you have any thoughts how can I store the value produced by the method?